# unblock steering wheel g920

Tags: c++, sdl, haptic-feedback

I try to determine the position of the g920 steering wheel by SDL2 library. (Windows 10 x64, mingw64 7.3.0, sdl v2.0.18)
Code:

```
SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_JOYSTICK );
SDL_JoystickEventState(SDL_ENABLE);
auto devPtr = SDL_JoystickOpen(0);
...
```

I can read the state values of the axes. But the wheel is locked (I think it is caused by the feedback mechanism). How can I unlock the wheel? I tried initialising the sdl library by SDL_INIT_HAPTIC and opening the haptic device, but it did not solve this problem.

Comment: I have a partial answer to my question. When I installed the Windows 10 SDK (it contains the directx sdk), my wheel started creating forced feedback effects. But I can't figure out how it works because I know that Directx 12 is already installed in Windows 10. And I do not know why I get an error message after every sdl command, and these commands somehow do their job...